# What should a blazor component do when given a bad paramters

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a blazor component that I use inside blazor pages. It has the following:

```
/// <summary>
/// The Event.Id of the event we're displaying.
/// </summary>
[Parameter]
[SupplyParameterFromQuery(Name = "id")]
public string? EventId { get; set; }
```

If that is passed a value for a record that does not exist, that is an error. If I was in my main page blazor I would pop up a message and then redirect them to the page they came from.

What should I do in the child component? I don't want to throw an exception because the Id passed could have just been deleted by another user and therefore, I need to exit gracefully, but it is not an error in the meaning if an ArgumentException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ErrorBoundary` Component.  You can do anything you want in the `ErrorContent` including navigating to another page.

A simple Component:

```cs
<h3>Component</h3>

@code {
    [Parameter] public int Id { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        if (this.Id > 10)
        {
            //Do some logging
            throw new RecordNotFoundException("ID is too big, I can't find that record");
        }
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Exception:

```cs
public class RecordNotFoundException : Exception
{
    public RecordNotFoundException(string messsage) :base(messsage) { }

}
```

And main page:

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />

<ErrorBoundary>
    <ChildContent>
        <Component Id="Id" />
    </ChildContent>
    <ErrorContent>
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            @context.Message
        </div>
    </ErrorContent>
</ErrorBoundary>

@code {
    [Parameter][SupplyParameterFromQuery(Name = "id")] public int Id { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        var x = this.Id;
        base.OnInitialized();
    }
}
```

[image]